# React conditional rendering: (a)wait for children to be mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have a React class component that renders `null` by default, and some children after an `activate()` function is called. Roughly like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    ...

    activate() {

        this.setState({showComponent: true})

    }

    ...

    render() {
        if (this.state.showComponent) {
            return <Child />
        } else {
            return null
        }
    
    }
}
```

I have an external JavaScript script in which I interact with the `MyComponent` (call activate function).

To keep it short, my problem is that after calling activate() in this external JS script and trying to access HTMLElements in the `<Child />` component right after (with `document.getElementById`) I get null pointers as the `<Child />` component is rendered asynchronously a bit later.

Is there a way to adapt the `activate()` function in `MyComponent` to 'wait' for all children in `<Child />` to be mounted?

I already tried to exploit the async nature of setState and tried `async activate()` with `await this.setState({showComponent: true})` but this did not change the rendering order.

So in short, is there a way to wait for children to be rendered after you perform a setState update. I guess this is a bit of a special case as it involves conditional rendering and `MyComponent` initially renders nothing.

Happy about any ideas!:)

Comment: I would recomend using `useEffect` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about emitting a custom event on window object inside `componentDidMount` of `Child` component and listening for this event in the external javascript and accessing the HTML element in the event handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works pretty well! Just wondering if there is a solution that uses native React for this, so all that logic stays in the React component. For example, my gut feeling tells me there must be a way to exploit the callback argument in setState. Also experimented with approaches similar to @sourav-choudhary 's suggestion, but without finding a way to inherently delay the return of the activate function. Also looked a bit into returning a promise.

Comment: AFAIK, `Child` component will not be mounted as soon as state of `MyComponent` changes to `{showComponent: true}`. I am pretty sure there will be a delay and you might run into the same issue. I think the best way to ensure that the element is present is use `componentDidMount` inside the `Child` component.

Answer (score 0):

we can pass a function to child component which we can call in child's componentDidMount hooks , so when the child gets mounted , it will trigger that function ...  but keep in mind don't update any state variable of parent component in that passed function otherwise it will stuck in a loop (coz as the state variable changes , it will re- render all the child component and eventually component did mount will also be called ...)

---

```
    class MyComponent extends React.Component {

        ...

        activate() {

       this.setState({showComponent: true})

    }

        callback = ()=>{
       // function to be passed in child component 
      // don't update any state variable here .. 
        }

      ...

     render() {
      if (this.state.showComponent) {
        return <Child callback={this.callback} />
     } else {
         return null
     }

  }
}
```

---

```
  class child extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
    super(props)
 }

   componentDidMount(){
     this.props.callback() // this will be called when this child will be
```

mounted
}

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Something like this I already implemented. But I was puzzled what the content of this callback function will be. How can I wait for all children to be rendered with this?